# TableViewController is causing TabBar item title to change to navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I do not understand why the following code causes the tab that represents the TableViewController show the same title as the navigation bar title.

The following code uses an observer to the see the size of the navigation controller if the large title is collapsed the title text changes to "Small Title"

The issue with this is the tabBar when pressed is copying the navigation title of the viewController and using it as the tab bar title.

Comment: Hi @PeterDavon. I think you can use `self.navigationItem.title = "Whatever you want"` for different titles of tabBar and navigationBar. I hope it is works. Enjoy.

Comment: @EmreCiftci What? That is what I am doing, look at my code

Comment: where is your `self.navigationItem.title =` line? I guess I could not see this line in your code? You should set your navigationItem's title not your `self`'s title.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I'm sorry that is correct

Comment: I appreciate your help, I will delete the post because the solution is so simple

Comment: Hi @PeterDavon. I think you should not delete the post. For others can also benefit. Not all questions have to be difficult :) Enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set your `navigationItem`'s title

```
 self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
```

If you set `self`'s title you set them both.

```
self.title = "Title of navigation bar and tab bar"
```

Enjoy.